# Issue @@IDENTITY AND IDENT_CURRENT(tableName) SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

After `INSERT` record to the table with an identity column
I try to get identified by the way `SELECT` `@@IDENTITY` but it returns NULL, 
but I try to use ;
`SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('tableName')` 
this statement return I'm expected value

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `@@Identity`, nor should you use `ident_current()`.
The first answers a question that you probably don't want to ask, and the second is unreliable, [according to SQL Server expert Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current) (or, at least, that was the case back in January 2014, when this article was published).

You should be using the `output` clause if you're inserting more than one record, or `scope_identity()` if you're only inserting one.

Note that the `output` clause doesn't play nice with triggers, and `scope_identity()` will have problems if your target table have an `instead of insert` trigger.

For more information, you can read [Use the right tool to get identity values back after an insert](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/use-the-right-tool-to-get-identity-values-back-after-an-insert/) over on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

> **IDENT_CURRENT()** returns the last inserted identity value for a given table.
>
> **SCOPE_IDENTITY()** returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in any table in the current session and current scope.

Probably you execute `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the other session